# After reordering the items in Android recycler view the position is not updating

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview

In my app I am showing a list of buttons in a recycler view, with the help of ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback ,onMove function I am able to reorder the buttons but after reordering the position is not updating . For eg:- (If I dragged the button1 from 0 position to 1 position then button1 should show that it's new position is 1 but it is showing old position i.e. 0) Is there any thing that is changing so that
I could access it and get to know the new position of my button.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP
                | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END , 0) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    
                int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
    
                Collections.swap(datalist,fromPosition,toPosition);
    
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemMoved(fromPosition,toPosition);
                return false;
            }
    
    
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by notifying the entire data set in the adapter:

```
Collections.swap(datalist,fromPosition,toPosition);
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemMoved(fromPosition,toPosition);
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should update the views based on their new position.This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It indicates that any reflection of the data at position is out of date and should be updated.

```
  recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I think you have that backwards. This is a structural change event. See docs on `notifiyDataSetChanged`: "Structural changes are when items are inserted, removed or moved within the data set." That doc also advices to use `notifyItemRangeChanged` when applicable. This avoids re-binding everything.